# How to avoid custom jquery slider from "jumping"

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I keep getting jumping in this banner. I know its sizing but I would like to keep this responsive. I created a custom slider in wordpress. Needs to be 100% width> Here is a link to the fiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/SCATORY/rntnht3j/2/

```
<section id="banners">
    <div class="banner bone">
        <a href="http://investors.gobio.com/news/" target="_blank">
            <img style="width:100%;" src="https://www.gobio.com/research/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/05/VirtualScopics_BTR_banner.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="banner2 btwo">
        <img style="width:100%;" src="http://www.gobio.com/research/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/05/EvriBeat_WebHomeSliderGraphic_R1.jpg">
    </div>
</section>
```

Heres the HTML

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function playslider() {
        $(".banner").fadeIn(800).delay(3600).fadeOut(800);
        $(".banner2").delay(5200).fadeIn(800).delay(3600).fadeOut(800, playslider);
    }
    playslider();
});
```

The Jquery

```
#banners {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #340004;
  display: block;
}
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  Height: 100%;
  background-color: #340004;
}
.banner2 {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  Height: 100%;
  background-color: #520002;
}
```

and the css

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "jumping". Looking at the fiddle, I can't tell what you're referring to.

Comment: Not able to understand what the real issue is. If you are trying to remove the padding of the body, set `padding:0` for body.

Comment: In your CSS, the 'H' in height is capitalized for .banner and .banner2 classes. Fix those and try a fixed height (change min-height to height) in #banners.

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback function to call the next slide instead of issuing a delay that is equal to the previous slides animations and delays.

Setting a delay equal to previous animations + delay(s) doesn't guarantee that it will actually run right after the previous animation due to slight delays that may pile up in the event queue.

There's a number of improvements that could be made to the code but this is the most simplistic solution to your problem. Provide a callback function that gets run at the end of `fadeOut()` for `$(".banner")` just as you have done of `$(".banner2")`.

```js
function playslider() {

    $( ".banner" ).fadeIn( 800 ).delay( 3600 ).fadeOut( 800, function () {
        $( ".banner2" ).fadeIn( 800 ).delay( 3600 ).fadeOut( 800, playslider );
    } );

}
```